# Should I use Apache Drill or Apache Solr?

Tags: apache, solr, apache-drill

I have a MongoDB database that contains a collection with millions of documents, what I need is query through these documents depending on certain conditions in the columns.. 
I read intensely the documentation of Apache Drill and since it allows writing queries in SQL it interests me but I'm afraid about the performance.
My query would be:

```
select * from table where col1= cond1 and col2= cond2 ... and col12=cond12;
```

Only two conditions are mandatory but at most 12 conditions on different 'columns'
Is Solr more suited for this ? or does Apache Drill suitable for the job ? 
I really looked everywhere and the documentation of Apache Drill is more rich.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Apache Solr. I used Drill for querying the oracle databases.

One of the main advantage of Apache drill is you can query across multiple databases. You just need to configure the sources & directly query them. This the biggest advantage of Apache drill. It was proved that its a best query among many other technologies. (Refer to the links)

You can refer one of my answer about the limitations & advantages of Apache Drill.

[What are the limitations of apache drill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388810/what-are-the-limitations-of-apache-drill/37474822#37474822)

Some other references to get to know about Drill very fast.

https://drill.apache.org/faq/
https://www.mapr.com/blog/top-10-reasons-using-apache-drill-now-part-mapr-distribution-including-hadoop

Comment: Thank you, so it's safe to say that Apache Drill is suitable for this kind of job (because it seemed to me like the kind of queries that might be suitable for a search engine)

Comment: Yeah its safe, Apache Drill is the inspired open source project based on the Google's Dremel (Ref: http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36632.html https://github.com/apache/drill)